# MVC3 and charting with 3 datasets (series i think)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

OK - since some jack downgraded my question....   i'll change the words a little bit....

I am using the built in controls from MS (System.Web.Helpers) to present the chart.

I think the correct way to state this is....

How do i code up the controller to present the graph displayed below?

I have the data from the last 8 quarters, from the six different items that are being tracked, and the total count of the items sold per quarter per item.

How would i create a bar graph to display like the graph below, using c#?

Using Razor, c# and mvc, i need to present a bargraph with three datasets.

I'll try to explain the way i would like to chart to look, then an ascii picture.

There will be six major columns, each column will have eight bars.  The column heights will be a numeric value of units sold.

The five major columns are certain items that want to be tracked when sold, the eight bars are the quantity of items sold over the last two years (8 quarters)  the values will be zero to ~500 items sold.

Here is the ascii image (sorry)

[image: quick screenie]

Comment: Are you asking what library you can use to chart data on an MVC3 application?

Answer (score 0):

if you're asking for ways to create charts in MVC3, you can look into the telerik MVC extensions (soon to be replaced with Kendo, but that's still in beta right now).
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/chart.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a excelent lib for charts, just create the script and done!

download, examples -> http://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can see is to do a RadGrid with 5 columns and you create 5 separate chart.